# I'm building a large scale AJAX app, am I doing this right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, web-applications

I started building this large scale app, but i want to make sure I'm doing it right and if not, what you would change before I got too deep into it. In short, it's a council agenda app. They can create agendas online via an AJAX app and publish, print, etc.

My directory structure is: `/css`, `/images`, `/js`, `/templates`, and of course, the index.html file.

`/css` contains whatever jQuery plugin CSS, `resets.css` and `main.css`.

`/js` contains: `app.js`, `ui.js`, `functions.js`, `keyboard-shortcuts.js`, `mouse-events.js`, `api-wrapper.js` and whatever plugins and jQuery.

`keyboard-shortcuts.js` contains a bunch of, well, keyboard shortcuts like copy, paste, app navigation, etc. This is the same for `mouse-events.js`. Contains events like drag&drop, sorting, right click menus, etc.

`ui.js` has stuff to render the UI. For example, custom scrollbars, action menu (the File, Edit, etc menu), and re-rendering of UI on resizing, etc.

`app.js` is the beef of it. It has my personal API for interacting with the app. The code so far is:

```
var app = function(){
  var _settings = {
    templatePath: 'templates/'
  }
  var api = {
  /**
   * resetUI Re-renders the UI. Use in resizing, click, and load events for example.
   * @returns {object} It re-renders the UI and returns the app() object for chaining
   */
    resetUI: function(){
      $('#sidebar,#editor,#preview').css({height:$(window).height()-$('header').outerHeight()-$('footer').outerHeight()+'px'});
      $('#preview').jScrollPane();
      return this;
    },
    /**
     * actionMenu opens and closes the action menu at the top of the UI
     * @param action {string} Can be "open" or "close" and does what it sounds like. If "open" see "item" param
     * @param item {object} Is only needed for the "open" action. It gives a reference of what item is clicked on
     * @returns {object} Returns the app() object for chaining.
     */
    actionMenu: function(action,item){
      if(action == 'open'){
        $('body').bind('click.contextMenus',function() { app().actionMenu('close') });
        $(item).addClass('active').find('ol').css({display:'block',top:$(item).outerHeight()+'px'});
      }
      else if(action == 'close'){
        $('#menu .active').removeClass('active');
        $('#menu > ol > li ol').css({display:'none'});
        $('body').unbind('click.contextMenus');
      }
      return this;
    },
    /**
     * modal() simply takes care of the modals. Lots of params also make it easy.
     */
    modal: function(options){
       var defaults = {
        title: 'Message',
        content:'',
        animationSpeed:150,
        beforeLoad:function(){},
        onLoad:function(){},
        afterLoad:function(){},
        beforeClose:function(){},
        onClose:function(){},
        afterClose:function(){}
      }
      var settings = $.extend({},defaults,options);
      var modalWrapper = $('#modal-wrapper');
      if(typeof options == 'string'){
        if(options == 'close'){
          $('#modal-buttons [href*=close]').unbind('click.modalClose');
          settings.beforeClose.call(this,modalWrapper)
          modalWrapper.fadeOut(animationSpeed);
        }
      }
      else{
        settings.beforeLoad();
        $.get(_settings.templatePath+'modal.html',function(html){
          var newHTML = $.template(html,{"title":settings.title,"content":settings.content});
          $('body').prepend(newHTML).find('#modal-wrapper').css({
            left:($(window).width()/2-modalWrapper.outerWidth()/2)+'px',
            top:($(window).height()/2-modalWrapper.outerHeight()/2)+'px'
          }).fadeIn(settings.animationSpeed,function(){
            settings.afterLoad.call(this,modalWrapper);
          });
          settings.onLoad.call(this,modalWrapper);

          $('#modal-buttons [href*=close]').bind('click.modalClose',function(){app().modal('close')});

        });
      }
    }
  }
  return api;
}
```

So you can use it like `app().modal({title:'Hello World'})` or `app().actionMenu('open',this).resetUI()`. Etc and more as the app is built out.

The `functions.js` file is simply misc. functions/tasks that don't fall into the other places, such as `$.template()` which parses my templates (see next paragraph).

Lastly for the `/js`, the `api-wrapper.js` is a wrapper for make working with the internal API (which is built with CF) easier. It's not the most user friendly API, so I figured for my own sanity and future devs it'd be easier to make it more simple. You get functionality like `api().post('agenda');` or `api().remove('agenda',124);`

Also, the last directory, `/templates` contains .html templates such `modal.html`. Used for HTML that is taken in chunks that will have just some of the code modified. For example, modal.html looks like (so far):

```
<div id="modal-wrapper">
  <div id="modal-buttons"><a href="#close">(X)</a></div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div id="modal-content">
    {{content}}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-controls"></div>
</div>
<div id="modal-overlay"></div>
```

So, am i on the right path? It's a completely front end app on my end. I just have a CF & M$ SQL DB that i interact with, with an API a backend dev built.

Feedback very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have some sensible structure in place. But I would suggest creating more decoupled and self-contained units (e.g UI components) in case the application is a really large one.

Have a look at:
http://boilerplatejs.org

It is not a library, but a framework that integrates some industry leading libraries with accepted patterns for large scale javascript development. May be some of the ideas in BoilerplateJS would assist you further.

Comment: I wish back then I would have actually split it into modules and into an MVC framework, but unfortunately, no :\ however, since this project I've done all projects with a more decoupled structure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the app function for namespace? If so, you could make it an object instead of a function. Then you could do app.modal({title:'Hello World'}). So, var app = {...}

Comment: Thanks good suggestion. Since I wont need any params that might be a good idea.

Comment: Awh, but now i remember. I have it like that so that i can have internal functions and vars like `_settings` for example. How would you rewrite `app.js` so that stuff still worked?